# Ant Freezes with no warning on exception

Tags: java, ant, build, freeze

I have been experiencing a weird problem that I can't find a solution to. When I am running a project through ant and there's an uncaught exception, ant simply freezes with absolutely no error. Here is my build file. This is a multi threaded environment, also

```
    <fileset id="masterlibs" dir="${lib.dir}">
            <patternset>
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
            </patternset>
    </fileset>

    <target name="clean">
            <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="init">
            <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
            <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
                    <classpath>
                            <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
                            <fileset refid="masterlibs"/>
                    </classpath>
            </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="compile">
            <java classname="stockData.AlertHandler" fork="true">
                    <classpath>
                            <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
                            <fileset refid="masterlibs"/>
                    </classpath>
                    <arg line="true"/>
                    <arg line="true"/>
                    <arg line="true"/>
                    <arg line="true"/>
                    <arg line="false"/>
                    <arg line="27_4"/>

                    <arg line="false"/>
            </java>
    </target>
```

Comment: You could add `<echo>` statements before/after each target to pinpoint where it is "frozen".  It might just be busy running the "run" target(forever).  

Does your stockData.AlertHandler ever terminate?  If you kill the stockData.AlertHandler process, does the ANT build complete?

Comment: The program is used to analyze stock information, so it runs for 6.5 hours a day (from 9:30am to 4:00pm). stockData.AlertHandler contains the main method which runs for this 6.5 hours. The build completes fine 99% of the time and at the end of the day gives me "Build Successful", but occasionally it freezes with absolutely no indication of why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ctrl+Break](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/) will show you a dump of threads and indicate what each is doing (plus any deadlocks). I'm guessing it's your spawned `AlertHandler` process and it may be easier to debug this outside the Ant environment.

If Ctrl+Break doesn't work (from the article)

> On UNIX platforms you can send a
>   signal to a program by using the kill
>   command. This is the quit signal,
>   which is handled by the JVM. For
>   example, on Solaris you can use the
>   command kill -QUIT process_id, where
>   process_id is the process number of
>   your Java program.

Comment: It's running on a Linux environment and Control+C gives nothing. Is there an equivalent feature in Linux that will give a dump?

Answer (score 0):

Ant can sometimes freeze when it runs a java class that asks for interactive input.  Is it possible that your AlertData class asks for input?